# drupal--hook_menu

Tags: drupal, module, hook

the info file is right,the following is my module file code. when i access the http://localhost/drupal/mymenu  why it can't work.

```
  <?php
 function mymenu(){
    $item = array();
  $item['mymenu'] = array(
       'description'=>'test1',
      'page callback'=>'mymenu_test',
      'access arguments' => array('access mymenu'),
     'type'=>MENU_CALLBACK,
 );
 return $item;
 }

  function mymenu_perm(){
   return array('access mymenu');
  }

 function mymenu_test() {
 $output = 'hello world';
 return $output;
}
```

i have gave the 'access mymenu' permission to the anonymous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

`function mymenu_menu() {
 ...
}`

You don't need the $item = array(); there also.

Answer (score 1):

whenever you see a api function with hook_something, you have to replace the 'hook' part with the name of your module

in this case it's indeed mymenu_menu

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: use function name as `modulename_menu` and use  `'access arguments' => array('access content')`.

```
<?php
  function test_menu(){
  $item = array();
  $item['mymenu'] = array(
  'description'=>'test1',
  'page callback'=>'mymenu_test',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type'=>MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $item;
  }

  function mymenu_test() {
  $output = 'hello world';
  return $output;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to flush menu cache(at least two times in drupal 7) after adding menu item with hook_menu.